# Phonegap Local SQLite to remote MySQL

Tags: sqlite, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I'm making an in-house application for a company and they want me to use Phonegap for the mobile application. After searching, I decided to go on and use SQLite plugin for the local storage but they have this requirement that when the device goes online all the data on the local storage will synced automatically to the remote MYSql db. I read about deferred functions in jQuery but I'm not quite familiar on how to use them.

Are there any alternatives to achieve this requirement?

Comment: As per my view, you have to use server scripting language like php, to push the local storage data or sqlite data to mysql db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently investigating to achieve a similar goal.

I need to develop an IONIC/Phonegap app that can potentially do CRUD operations with the followings DB engines:  MySQL / Postgres / Microsoft SQL Server / Oracle (not simultaneously).

[TypeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/) seems to be the solution, but I still couldn't connect from Android device to remote MySQL DB. 
If you work with TypeORM over NodeJS directly is very easy to have an example up and running and do some CRUD operations with the supported DB engines (just follow the examples and documentation in the previous link).

I'm asking at https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/548 if anybody has achieved an Android-MySQL connection using TypeORM.